# Drupal 8 PHPUnit testing Invalid Credentials

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, drupal-8

I have a class I want to test that uses this [module](https://github.com/snowcap/Emarsys) PHP HTTP client for Emarsys webservice, but when I try to test it, I will always get `$response` as "Credentials are invalid" from the module itself.

Here's a snippet of my code: (Given that I was able to correctly create my `setUp()` for Test Class since I was able to use it for other tests)

Test.php

```php
Class TestClass extends UnitTestCase {
    public function testCreateWithValidEmail() {

        $newsletter = new Newsletter();

        $form = new FormState();
        $form->setValue('email', 'abc@def.ghi');

        $response = $newsletter->register($form);

        // Assertion here
    }
}
```

Class.php

```php
use Snowcap\Emarsys\CurlClient;
use Snowcap\Emarsys\Client;

Class Newsletter {
    public function register(FormStateInterface $state){
          $emailData = $state->getValue('email');

          $httpClient = new CurlClient();
          $client = new Client($httpClient, $api_username, $api_secret);
          $someData = [
             "3" => $emailData, // since 3 is the index ID for email
             // ...more data here
          ];

          $response = $client->createContact($someData);
    }
}
```

Do I have to create a mock of something here to pass a dummy api and secret then force a valid response from `createContact`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the good direction. But that `Newsletter` class needs the `$httpClient` injected.

So you will be able to do:

```
$client = $this->getMockBuilder(Snowcap\Emarsys\CurlClient::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$response = $this->getMockBuilder(ResponseInterface::class)
  ->disableOriginalConstructor()
  ->getMock();
$response->expects($this->any())
  ->method('getStatusCode')
  ->willReturn(Response::HTTP_OK);
$client->expects($this->any())
  ->method('createContact')
  ->with($someData)
  ->will($this->returnValue($response));

$newsletter = new Newsletter($client);
$response = $newsletter->register($form);
// Assertion here
```

Comment: I tried a different approach where I still used a dependency injection to fix the response but this also worked when I tried it. Thanks!